# Как использовать CDN-JS пакет в TS-скрипте на jsfiddle.net?

Tags: typescript, импорт, typescript-типы, cdn, jsfiddle

Например у меня есть рабочий JS-скрипт [sfiddle-example-js](https://jsfiddle.net/Artyom_Ionash/px913nja/49/):

```js
const { parallelLimit } = async

;(async () => {
  const tasks = Array(10)
    .fill(null)
    .map((item, i) => async () => i)
  const limit = 5
  await parallelLimit(tasks, limit)
    .then((results) => console.log(results.join(',')))
})()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/async/3.2.3/async.js"></script>
```

И когда я [переключаю его на TypeScript](https://jsfiddle.net/Artyom_Ionash/px913nja/66/), он перестаёт работать.

В локальном проекте мне, теоретически, нужно было бы подключить этот пакет,

> npm i --save-dev @types/async

но как решить эту проблему на платформе [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: как-то странно там работает. Плюс, непонятно какая версия typescript используется. Попробуй другие платформы использовать для typescript, типа plnkr, stackblitz или codesandbox какие-нибудь

Comment: `npm i --save-dev @types/async` это установка типов (.d.ts) пакета [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async), вы ведь понимаете это?

Comment: @nörbörnën Да, я это понимаю. И на понимании этого, решение проблемы для меня стопорится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net) плохо подходит для публикации кода на TypeScript,
и скорее всего проблема в такой постановке не имеет решения.

Для публикации TypeScript-кода лучше пользоваться сервисом [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-3kwu2b?file=index.ts).